# How do you restart an asp.net web forms application?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am getting this error after publishing my application:

The directory '/App_GlobalResources/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled.

My googling has yielded many recommendations to "restart my application" only I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Try opening IIS and restarting the Website, and recycle the app pool

Answer (score 0):

To restart your application you can open web.config in an editor, add a space somewhere, and save it. Please be aware that if you are using in-process session state the application pool will recycle, causing session state to be lost. However, this method has the benefit of not affecting web applications in other application pools.

If you want only this application to be affected, you could place it in its own application pool, or use one of the other session-state modes. [Session State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your website and Restart your application pool from IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing locally, open a command prompt and type `iisreset` If you do this on a production machine you're going to take ALL the sites on that machine down during the reset. It's usually quick, but some sites can't have downtime during peak hours...

On a server, stop the app and app pool, then start them again.